# Resistor that can be placed like a jumper

Tags: resistors, jumper

I want to make a relay output to be configurable by the client as NO/NC or guarded by resistors (10k opened, 1k closed).

A solution I have been thinking about uses resistors that can be placed like a jumper on a pin header, like this:

[image]
A quick search for existence of this jumper type yielded nothing. Does anyone know if this is an actually available component? Any other (albeit simple for untrained end users) solutions are welcomed.

Comment: Couldn't you just put a resistor inline with the header, and then use a jumper to connect this resistor to the relay output? Why does the resistor itself need to be placed like a jumper?

Comment: @Doodle, the relay output must be configurable between normally opened/normally closed  or 10k/1k. To change it to normally opened/normally closed, the 1k resistor needs to be exchanged (shorted) with a "real" jumper and the 10k resistor removed. I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Why the complication (and it is a serious complication) when you can use simple user-selectable jumpers to achieve what you want.

Comment: @Andy Aka, we need a solution that is easily configurable by an untrained end user. Being more complicated to manufacture is less of a problem.

Comment: What's easier than moving a jumper from one position to another?

Comment: [Like this](https://cdn.sparkfun.com//assets/parts/2/4/0/7/09044-04-L.jpg)

Comment: @Andy Aka, I get what you mean to say. I looked into other ways to make this configurable, but they all require more pins on the header and more ways for the end user to do it wrong. The 10k resistor could be made on the board, and activated with a jumper. The 1k resistorss are more of a problem, because they must either be shorted, or opened. The figure attached with my question shows all ways the output can be configured. The option to exchange "output opened" with 10k and "output shorted" with 1k is a requirement by Dutch Standard to make the system tamper-proof.

Comment: Even if you use jumpers, those will be misplaced and disappear 15 minutes after the box is opened. I would recommend DIP switches.

Comment: @Bart Well, the diagram you show makes little sense to me but I accept your argument for the reasons why. To make this clear, you should amend you question with the rules and explicitly say how the resistive jumpers need to be connected to get what you want - I can't tell what you want from your diagram.

Comment: Or place a female pin header on the board - those will accept resistor leads directly, but is that isn't really a formfactor suitable for end users.

Comment: I updated the question with a more complete schematic. Drawn in ACAD for sake of simplicity.

Comment: @Arcatus, the box will not be opened, though the cable might get damaged for a number of reasons.

Comment: @Bart As this is configurable by the client they need to manage these special jumpers, and they will loose them very quickly.

Comment: @Arcatus, maybe. Our competion does something similar, though I didn't get my hands on their units yet to find out how they do it.

Comment: Rather than use special jumpers, instead have a separate jumper position for when they want resistive protection or not. Have the resistors on the board.

Comment: @Arcatus, neither will using female headers and through hole resistors be acceptable to the inspection office that will cast their final approval/disapproval vote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use 3-way headers instead of 2-ways for the jumpers. That way, you can shift the jumper by 1 position to the Resistive Protection position.

[image]

Comment: We will take this one in consideration. Two extra pins might be acceptable.

Comment: In my experience, using "special" components tends to lead to complications down the line, usually with supply.

Comment: Maybe the competitors have them specially made, so the client has to turn to them when the jumpers get lost. Vendor lock-in is not our policy, so we will not even consider that.

Comment: This is the approach that we had in mind too. We will go with this one. Interesting detail is that the competitor uses indeed a kind of resistor with the form factor of a jumper, probably custom made, and maybe even by themselves.